# Looking for a dropup directive for Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to implement a dropup menu (menu that opens above the button) in Angular.js that would behave similarly to the ".dropup" class in Boostrap.

Is there a directive that does this or simple instructions to create one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a `dropdown` directive that actually uses Bootstrap (like the [UI Bootstrap Dropdown directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown)), there's no reason you can't apply the `.dropup` class itself to that dropdown and have it work as expected.

```
<div class="btn-group dropup" dropdown> <!-- note the dropup class -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" ng-disabled="disabled">
    Button dropup <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li>Stuff</li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's a plunker to demonstrate: http://plnkr.co/edit/pzoRuVOjHHaBLryCv7RA

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about a navigation bar-type thing, rather than a `<select>` element, I'd go with the following CSS:

```
.nav ul li {
  position: relative;
}
.nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  postion: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Adding in your own CCS flavorings and supplement that with jQuery animation:

```
$('.nav ul li').hover(function() {
  $(this).children('ul').stop().slideDown();
}, function() {
  $(this).children('ul').stop().slideUp();
});
```

The `stop()` prevents the animations from stacking up in an obnoxious queue. Despite the naming, `slideDown()` will open the submenu upwards and `slideUp()` will close it downwards because you've affixed the bottom of the element with your CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I understand I can do this with Jquery, however I'm looking for an Angular directive similar to this: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown.